# Alignment in Row and Columns instead padding flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm going deeper on flutter learning so I have a doubt :
I'm developing an app with flutter and I'm positioning all the widgets with "Alignment" because I don't like to move widgets on the screen with "padding". It gives overflows too many times and changing devices some troubles could rise (Screen size).

So I would like to know how to move widgets inside row and columns changing their size and all their properties without creating new problems.

My main fear is the overflow by pixel on the screen.

I read something about some widgets : Flexible, Expanded, Flex...I'm studying their behavior but I need help.

This is my code :

```
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          flex:1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    100, 0, 0, 0,
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: 
                      AssetImage('assets/images/fallout.png'),
                    minRadius: 100,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          flex:1,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0, 0, 0, 0,),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                    child: TextField(
                      enabled: false,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                            width: 3.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Descrizione :',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
          ],
        ),
    ),
);
}
}
```

Can I replace "padding" with "alignment" or something that moves widgets on the screen using a percentage of the screen not fixed values?

Comment: please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `Align` widget for the aligment  purpose like center, right,top..etc, Along with you need to use the `MediaQuery` to get the device width and height properly, 
Example :- For setting the height and width of any widget , will like below

```
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8, /// YOU CAN DEFINE FROM 0.1 TO 1 AS YOUR REQUUIRMENT
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2,
```

Please check the below example of it.

```
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  var inputVales;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/fallout.png'),
                  minRadius: 100,
                )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.2,
                  child: TextField(
                    enabled: false,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                          width: 3.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Descrizione :',
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And output will be follow 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes! what you are looking for is `MediaQuery` to get the screen's attributes

For example to get the screen width you use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

**Edited:**

You can try one of these two examples using `Align` for more precision

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: MyWidget(),
        ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment(-0.9, -0.9),
            child: MyWidget(),
        )
```

Alternatively you can also try the `Positioned` widget :

```
Positioned(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.5,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width+10,
        left: -5,
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.42,
        child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      ),
```

Comment: Nice, thank you ! It'll be perfect if I could move the widget on an exact point of the screen, something like : SetWidgetIn( horizontal : x, vertical : y). I get the width and height than I can set my widgets where I want. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: @MichealRoss please accept the answer that helped you to close this post

Comment: Ok how can I do this?

Comment: @MichealRoss hit the check mark next to the answer to accept it, not comments like this but the answer and welcome to stackoverflow